# Hiding HTML link in href attribute

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

OK, I'm not that good with HTML but I'll try to express myself as good as possible.

Lets say I have a link for a game in href attribute. By using JS on.click, as soon as user clicks on the link, he gets a pop-up window that forces him to subscribe. After they subcribe, the link is automatically opened and download starts.

But the problem is that the link is visible, so he can simply right click it, copy link location, paste it and ... well you got the idea. Also while hovering the link, its shown in the bottom (depending on your browser).

How to hide that link from user (still need to use on mouse click)?

He doesn't need to see it, it opens as soon as he subscribes.

Thankful

Comment: You should do it on server side.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M is right. You should use AJAX and custom server side scripts to achieve this not simply client side. You can only fully control stuff on the server.

Comment: Why not just remove the URL from the markup and store it in your JavaScript.

Comment: @osahyoun It's not a good idea. User can search in the javascript source to find the link. You should handle such things on server side.

Comment: hey, what you are talking about doesn't need to be complicated by server side stuff... Go With Sumit Malik answer

Comment: @ryanc1256 Maybe it's the answer, but it's not a good idea. Because user can bypass it

Comment: @Siamak.A.M Don't get me wrong, but I think he want's it so the user cant see the link, but will be able to click on it... So therefore you use the `href"#"` to hide the link, but still be able to click on the link, but then if you don't what the user to be able to see the link at all the only way is to store a generic key in the server and pull it back later when the user clicks on the link... But that does a lot more coding than is necessary...

Comment: And yes, I should mention that if link appears in Source code it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 4):

It is better if you give `href='#'` and use the same JS function to redirect the user to the link.

To use some of the text from the other Answerer..

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.location = 'my-website.com/download/super-game.zip';"> Download link </a>
```

This Will Open the link but I would do it something like this...

```
  <a href="#" onClick="download('my-website.com/download/super-game.zip')"> Download link </a>
```

and then in a JavaScript file

```
function download(link)
{
 window.location = link;
 return false;
}
```

This is how I would do it but its very silly... By silly I mean stupid, why do you want a user be able to click on the but not see the link? there is only one way to do it, its to use a server side language, and therefore the user won't be able to see the link...

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you give href='#' and use the same JS function to redirect the user to the link.

Comment: <a href="http://www.my-website.com/download/super-game.zip" onClick="javascript:do.something(); return false;">Download this great game</a>

If I replace the link in href with #, where would I put the actual link?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

GIT : https://github.com/michaelhartomo/js-ninja-href

## js-ninja-href

Javascript native library to hide / cloak your real url link.

Really useful to hide your referral link.

Get all your lost revenue, because some people don't want to use your referral link.

It will innocently show a clean url, but when the user click ( left , middle, right ) it will redirect them to somewhere else.

Install
Download and extract the .zip file: https://github.com/michaelhartomo/js-ninja-href/archive/master.zip

Setup
Include the script: ninja-href.min.js

```
<script src="js/ninja-href.min.js"></script>
```

Now run the ninja-href function ( by default, it will listen to ninja-href class )

```
ninja_href(".ninja-href");
```

Set the link you want to hide / cloak just like this ( open in new window ):

```
<a href="http://google.com/" class="ninja-href" data-ninja-url="http://frozenfire.us/" data-ninja-target="_blank"> Go to Google </a>
```

You can also open the link in current window :

```
<a href="https://tomplayer.top/" class="ninja-href" data-ninja-url="https://m.do.co/c/9072c848dc6e" data-ninja-target="_self"> TOP Charts 100 WORLD & 50 K-POP! </a>
```

Very useful to cloak referral link just like this :

```
<a href="https://google.com/free/RlJPWkVORklSRS1UT01QTEFZRVIuQVBQLU1JQ0hBRUxIQVJUT01PLkNPTQ==" class="ninja-href" data-ninja-url="https://m.do.co/c/9072c848dc6e" data-ninja-target="_self"> GET FREE 10 USD FOR SSD VPS HOSTING! ( You can use it for 2 months ) </a>
```

jsFiddle Example : https://jsfiddle.net/t5f7n7gL/1/